# how to solve problem of number separator in chrome

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm facing a problem in `</v-text-field>` at a number's separator, I want it to be ***dot*** like in `Firefox` not ***a comma*** like `chrome`

In `FireFox`:

[image]

In `Chrome`:

[image]

*template:*

```html
<v-text-field type="number" v-model="number" label="price"></v-text-field>
```

*script*

```js
data: () => ({
    number: 498.23
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set locale in your `input` tag. `lang` is descripted your locale.

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" lang="en"/>

<input type="number" step="0.01" lang="tr"/>
```

try these examples

Comment: Yes, It changes the separator but only in firefox when doing that in chrome it won't just be fixed with the separator as a comma! I think it's a bug?

Comment: you are right. chrome not changed. you can change it with some code. when you save your data or send to back-end, you can do like this below.
`this.number = parseFloat(this.number.toString().replace(',','.'))`
or
`this.number = parseFloat(this.number.toString().replace('.',','))`